# Bind Ant target to "Build Project" in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ant, netbeans-plugins

I just started using Netbeans for my PHP projects. I'm using Netbeans mostly for the xdebug functionality. I have a script that I run through the PHP CLI to "build" cached files.

Currently the "Build Project" and "Clean and Build Project" options are grayed out. I would like to make these actions run different scripts.

I figured the Ant plugin would be the best way to go, but I can't seem to figure out how to bind the target to this action.

Anyone know how to do this? If there is another way I'm not tied to Ant, I just want to attach shell scripts to those actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation with the PHP plugin. There is a bug report [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195706) that provides a patch to add this functionality. I'm not sure how to apply the patch though. There is a comment on this bug report that suggests an optional plugin may be created. If you want this functionality vote for it on the [bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195706).